# Access Google Apps Global Directory from Apple Mail, Outlook or Thunderbird?

Tags: g-suite

I wonder if this is possible. We are using Google Apps for Education. We have users running Apple Mail, Outlook 2011 or Thunderbird email clients. How could these email client apps access our domain global directory from Google Apps? 
Thanks much!